# htaccess settings for angularJS pushstate

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I'm using pushstate with AngularJS but I'm having some issues with the htaccess file.
This is the URL with HTML5mode false:

http://127.0.0.1/mpu/#!/Roma/home
(Roma is a variable)

At the moment I'm using this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.html
</ifModule>
```

And, as result, I have this:
http://127.0.0.1/mpu/home

But instead I need it with "Roma" after mpu

Can anyone help me to write the right htaccess please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read this article https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

**Updated**

This is the **.htaccess** file on my root folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

This is my virtual host ( I'm using Xampp on windows ).

Go to *C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra* and edit **httpd-vhosts.conf** file and don't forget to add also **127.0.0.1 example.local** in you host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Reboot the Apache server and you're good to go.

After this setup, this will be your code for the routing part in Angular

```
var Config = function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', { 
        url : '/',
        templateUrl : 'home.html'
    })
    .state('city', {
        url : '/:city/home',
        templateUrl : 'city.html'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

};

Config.$inject = [
    '$locationProvider',
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider'
];

app.config(Config);
```

Comment: Thank you. This one was the first I tried, but it didn't work at all. I thought it was because I'm testing in localhost....but the other one works (partially) also in localhost, so I presume it doesn't depend from that.

Comment: you put the .htaccess file in your root folder, do you? If you have the module rewrite installed, should work properly as it is in the article.
Maybe you should write more than that, so will be easy to understand your problem

Comment: If I use it I have this behavior: I load the index properly, I can navigate through the pages that don't require "Roma", but if I reload the page (also in homepage) I have the error 404.
With the other setting, at least, I can refresh the page without problems.

Comment: The problem is simple, your server doesn't know how to handle that page because doesn't exist physically in your server. So with the .htaccess you can redirect everything to the index page so angular will handle everything.

Comment: Thank you for your guide. At the moment I'm using EasyPhp, not Xampp...I suppose it works as well.
I'm using also routeProvider instead of stateProvider, also this should be fine as well.
I'm quite sure that my only point is what I asked on my question: the .htaccess setting read only the {REQUEST_FILENAME} ignoring the first part (in the example "Roma")...if only I can find a way to tell the server to read it too, I think, it'll work perfectly with this setting (I'm pushing on it because I see that it worked perfectly for all the pages that don't required "Roma"). Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to use angular-ui-router and you'll see some benefits. I thought Rome was a dynamic parameter, so I put the :city param in the URL of the route. If you need it static, just do it. It works, I test it :) otherwise put more infos