# Angular 1.6 $http no error response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

```
function() {
        "use strict";
        angular.module("App").controller("LabCtrl", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$state", "$http", function($scope, a, b, $http) {

            a.labs = []; //declare an empty array

            $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'datalab.json'
            }).then(function (response){
                a.labs = response.data;
            },function (error){
                console.log(error);
            });

        }])
    }.call(this),
```

my html:

```
<li class="project-item" ng-repeat="lab in labs">   
            <img alt="img title" ng-src="{{lab.img}}"> 
            <span><strong>{{lab.title}}</strong><br>
            {{lab.desc}}</span> 
    </li>
```

without track by $index i get like 10000 results ? i only have 10 entries in my .json.
my error log is not working too. i get a 200 OK status for the file datalab.json but the file is called data/lab.json

lab.json

```
[
  {
    "title": "Lab #1",
    "desc": "iOS App Design.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/sports/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #2",
    "desc": "iOS app.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/abstract/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #3",
    "desc": "App Design.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/cats/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #4",
    "desc": "Website Design.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/fashion/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #5",
    "desc": "Illustration.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/nature/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #6",
    "desc": "Dribbble Concepts",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/technics/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #7",
    "desc": "Mac OS App.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/transport/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #8",
    "desc": "Website Design.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/city/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #9",
    "desc": "Website / Dashboard Design.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/nightlife/"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lab #10",
    "desc": "Website Design.",
    "img": "http://lorempixel.com/774/600/food/"
  }
]
```

maybe my .htaccess is the problem? (has to work with https) i have pushstate links etc. NewHomepage/labor/    NewHomepage/kontakt/
.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Comment: What is the result of `datalab.json` when you try to open it in the browser? Do you get some result?

Comment: yes i get the html from my index

Comment: As you commented on the other question - there's nothing wrong with your code. However, your web server may not return anything if the file located there doesn't exist. Your code is right so far - however, your web server serves something which it thinks is you requested (which it isn't).

Comment: i switched back to the good old simple hash url's without any extra htaccess    (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻ its working now^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss-wrote your controller, you are missing the dependencies for your main app module. And for using "$state" you need to inject "ngRoute".
Here is your code working:

```
    (function() {
        "use strict";
         angular.module("App",[]).controller("LabCtrl", ["$rootScope", "$scope", 
        "$http", function($rootScope,$scope, $http) {

        $scope.labs = []; //declare an empty array

        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'datalab.json'
        }).then(function (response){

            $scope.labs = response.data;
            // added this log after removing the "track by $index" in 
            // your html
            console.log(response.data.length);
        },function (error){
            console.log(error);
        });

    }])
})();
```

Comment: my functions etc. are working when i change  url: 'datalab.json' to  url: 'data/lab.json'  its working(10 results), but datalab.json gives me 10697 results

Comment: can you help me i think there is a problem with my htaccess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264669/angularjs-htaccess-pushstate-cant-open-files

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked with .htaccess before, but check this it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351333/htaccess-settings-for-angularjs-pushstate